# wrap everything between hr elements

Tags: jquery, wrapall

Trying to find a way to wrap all between hr tags in code, but nogo so far. Any advise on the code?

Here's what I'm doing right now (also as a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1go06br/1/)):

```js
$('hr').each(function() {
  $(this).next('hr').wrapAll('<div style="background-color:yellow"></div>');
});
```

```html
Text
<hr>
Text1
Text2
<hr>
Text3
<hr>
Text4
Text5
<hr>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"Please see fiddle"* Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). *(Edit: I've done it for you this time.)*

Comment: Thanks TJ, now I know for the future

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You forgot the jQuery script reference.

Comment: @MasterYoda: Only very briefly. :-)

Comment: Thought I included in the jsfiddle. But your correction still doesn't color yellow. Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: @KevinLindmark: You did include a fiddle. I'm saying: I should be **on-site**, in a snippet. Not **off-site**, in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't do a lot to help you around text nodes (other than [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)). Simplest thing here is probably to just use the DOM itself to find following sibling nodes (including text nodes), and then wrap them in the `div`; see comments:

```js
$('hr').each(function() {
  // Build an array of all nodes (including text nodes)
  // up to and not including the next HR if any
  var nodes = [];
  var n = this.nextSibling;
  while (n && n.nodeName != "HR") {
    nodes.push(n);
    n = n.nextSibling;
  }
  // Wrap them in a div
  $(nodes).wrapAll('<div style="background-color:yellow"></div>');
});
```

```html
Text
<hr>
Text1
Text2
<hr>
Text3
<hr>
Text4
Text5
<hr>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder, just a quick follow up. Worked fine in a html file but when I changed to xhtml format it acts a bit strange (all end divs gathered and the end instead of after each hr). The hr tag is xhtml compliant with <hr />, do you have any clue what in the code could be causing this in xhtml specifically?

Comment: @KevinLindmark: The above is working at the DOM level; how that DOM is built (HTML, XHTML) doesn't matter, it should still work. And seems to: http://jsbin.com/sojavuketo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @t-j-crowder Yes must be something else in my production code creating my issue. Thanks!